# REGEX - Data Validation

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have the following Google Spreadsheet.

[Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10Pqhq5wgLR5NLz_fhvOtKnu3dQ0cMK_j_vKbR736to4/edit?usp=sharing)

When users enter a name into any cell of column A of the sheet named "Unit Standards" I want them to enter that name in a particular format. That is, with the surname first in uppercase then a comma, then the first name in title case then if they are known by a different name that name to be title case in brackets e.g.

- BUSH, George
- TRUMP, Donald
- CLINTON, William (Bill)
- CARTER, James (Jimmy)
- SMITH-JONES, John
- ZETA-JONES, Catherine (Kate)

Someone else helped me with the following code which I have added to column A as a Data Validation.

```js
=REGEXMATCH(A10,"^[A-Z]+\b[',']\s[A-Z]{1}[a-z]+\b(\s([A-Z][a-z]+\b))?$")
```

You can see by the following image that some of the inputs are in violation so the formula is not quite right.

[image: Data Validation]

I would appreciate some help with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex matches all the cases you proposed:

```
[A-Z][A-Z' ]+(-[A-Z' ]+)*, [A-Z][a-z]+( \([A-Za-z]+\))?
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Added the cases proposed in comment.

Comment: Thank you - it now works for every possibility except ZETA-JONES, Catherine (Kate)

Comment: Is because zeta-jones have a dot.

Comment: Now it includes the dot

Comment: I'm impressed - that works perfectly. Thank you very much for your time and input.

Comment: Sorry - I have come across another 3 scenarios TE AMO, Eric, also O'BRIEN, Patrick and SMITH, Carl (CJ)..Would you mind helping me with these? And sorry again, the dot was a mistake

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXMATCH(A1:A10, "^([A-Z' -]+), ([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+)( \([A-ZA-z]+\))?$"))
```

[image: 0]